# Get the value of an auto increment PK column

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, sql

I've got the following table in MySql:
Contact:

- Id
- Name
- FirstName
- ...

Now, I'm writing an INSERT INTO in my c# program, but the Id column is defined to auto increment, so my statement looks like this:
**INSERT INTO Contact (Name, FirstName) VALUES ("Sander", "Declerck")**

So how can I get the new value for my object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue this query:

```
SELECT  LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

right after the `INSERT`.

Comment: As well, make sure this query goes out via the same connection as the insert query was done on - last_insert_id() is per-connection.

Comment: What if another client does an insert meanwhile?

Comment: @Igor: the function has session scope, it returns the last id inserted in this session.

Comment: @Quassnoi OK thanks, I guess I can be pretty sure it returns the right ID then.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use [SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), or your API wrapper might let you call [mysql_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html).